# Transparent material creating unwanted shadows on mesh behind

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, materials

Material for the eyelid mesh is a simple transparent node into material surface output. mesh uses a subdivision and shrinkwrap modifier in that order. It also only shows up in cycles render but not material preview.

Note the black spots
[image: Note the black spots]

Comment: did you try to "play" a bit with the offset of the shrinkwrap? might help.

Comment: Oh lol, I increased it by .0005 to .005 and it went away. Thanks.

Comment: you are welcome